# How to solve that odoo repository problem?

Tags: odoo-12

My github repository is => git@github.com:myatthiha1998/asdf-12.0.git

My odoo repository is => ssh://git@github.com/myatthiha1998/asdf-12.0.git#12.0

I face with following error.

Error when updating git from ssh://git@github.com/myatthiha1998/asdf-12.0.git#12.0
returncode: 128
output:
b'warning: Could not find remote branch 12.0 to clone.\nfatal: Remote branch 12.0 not found in upstream origin\n'
Consult our FAQ at https://apps.odoo.com/apps/faq .

Can someone help me , please? I want to upload my module to apps.odoo.com